# Storing Longitude and Latitude values

Tags: java

So I have 5000+ ship coordinates, They're Longitude & Latitude coordinates. I'm wondering what would be the best way to store these for each ship. Each ship will have an unknown amount of coordinates. 

Initially I was thinking a double 2D array similar too:

```
double [][] array = new double[][];
```

But I have no idea of the size I will need. 

I don't know if a `Hashmap` will work since there's no real "key", I was thinking an `ArrayList` of `List`'s, but I was not sure on the implementation and if it's the most viable option.

Comment: Start by creating a Coordinate class, containing a latitude and a longitude. Then, if you need a variable length list of coordinates, use a List<Coordinate>.

Comment: What's the real issue? It's a map of ships to their lists of lat/lng pairs. Do you actually need it in memory?

Comment: Is this a real life problem or a school / learning problem? If it's a real life problem, I'd suggest you start by designing the database tables

Comment: @ControlAltDel Who talked about DB here? Maybe he's not using a DB. You're making assumptions out of nothing.

Comment: @m0skit0 I am, it's true

Comment: You should seriously consider using `BigDecimal` for coordinates rather than doubles/floats.

Comment: @Powerlord why? do you really care if the coordinate isn't precise to the millionth of a micron?

Comment: As Powerlord said, if you care about [accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems), use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a `ShipCoordinates`class

```
public class ShipCoordinates {
    public final double latitude;
    public final double longitude;

    public ShipCoordinates(double lat, double lon) {
        latitude = lat;
        longitude = lon;
    }
}
```

And store these objects into a List

```
List<ShipCoordinates> shipCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();
// Example of valid ship coordinates off the coast of California :-)
shipCoordinates.add(new ShipCoordinates(36.385913, -127.441406));
```

Comment: I believe (90, 180) coordinates are illegal for ship position: they are fully covered with ice :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe hashmap is not sobad afterall. Consider this?

```
static class Coords {
 ...
}

Map<Coords, String> map = new HashMap<Coords, String>();
map.put(new Coords(1700, 1272), "Some_ship");
```

Comment: Need to implement `hashCode` and `equals` for `Coords`... Doesn't look like a good idea unless OP really clarifies what a map is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Ship {
    ArrayList<Coordinate> coordinates;
}

ArrayList<Ship> ships;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having a snippet of the data file to view it is hard to answer this.  ArrayList would seem ideal and creating objects of ships with their coordinates.

If you want to do hashmap my guess is that the best key would be the ship.